# Append listview with the same variable but different value each time

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I have variable a in a loop, it gives a different string each time

I want to add that string in `ListView`, without overwriting it, i searched for append `ListView`, but didn't find anything, i always got the last item which is the last a value in the `ListView`

I think I need to use `HashMap` or foreach, but i don't know how

in the image, each line is string `a` variable, so the variable will change every time

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LItMy.png] 
[image: https://i.imgur.com/RJnsXFm.png]

158 word

here's my code

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);
list.add(a);
simpleList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

UPDATE:

code

> a variable comes from console.log in javascript

```
siteView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage consoleMessag) {
                String imgDataUr= consoleMessag.message();

                if (imgDataUr.contains("heyyes")) {
                    String a=imgDataUr.substring(6); //this changed with different value each time
                    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);
                    Log.d("countries", a);

                        list.add(a);
                        simpleList.setAdapter(adapter);


               }
                return super.onConsoleMessage(consoleMessag);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Please post full code where you iterate variable `a`

Comment: @Ashish please check updated question, i add more codes