# split each value in different variable

Tags: java, sorting, split

**Related to: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60708673/edit**

I have variable `a` that is in loop, it change it value so

- a=mc
- a=dd
- a=jj

How can i split that values in different variables names ?

Like

- a0=mc
- a1=dd
- a2=jj

Using android java

*This code is in loop*

```
String a = imgDataUr.substring(6); //this changed with different value each time
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);
Log.d("countries", a);

list.add(a);
simpleList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

the purpose of my question is to put different variable name each time in `list.add(a);`  like

```
list.add(a1); //for the 1st loop 

list.add(a2); //for the 2nd loop ...
```

Comment: Store them in a `List` or an array, maybe?

Comment: @deHaar how can i do that ?

Comment: You want a [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html).

Comment: I may be able to help you if you post your code...

Comment: @deHaar check my previous question, it's related and have the codes, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60708673/append-listview-with-the-same-variable-but-different-value-each-time

Comment: Sorry, I cannot cross-answer two or more questions. That won't help anyone... Post your code here, please. Just a minimal reproducible example for the important part.

Comment: @deHaar i updated the question, please check

Comment: I don't really get why you are talking about different variable names if you are storing values... Where is this loop? Why haven't you posted it as well? I don't see the relation to the loop in this code.

Comment: @deHaar ok, let me explain, the values comes from javascript console.log, so, i use this function `const selector = "#main_table_countries > tbody:nth-child(2) > tr > td:nth-child(1)";
                            
                            document.querySelectorAll(selector).forEach(el => console.log("heyyes"+el.textContent.trim()));`
in this website https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/
tried it in chrome console, so, my idea is to give each value different variable to add in android listview so i can show all the list, instead of showing only the last value, check my related quest

Comment: OK, then it seems you should move the declaration of the list and the adapter outside the loop (above) and set the list to the adapter after the loop. Only do `list.add(a);` and the optional logging inside the loop.

Comment: @deHaar finally, thank you very very much, i understand now the problem, that fixed it, please post your comment as an answer and i'll accept it, really appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a new list in every iteration which then gets just a single item. In addition, you create an adapter each iteration and set the single-itened list.

Do it like this:

1. create the list and the adapter before the loop
2. in the loop, just add `a` to the list and maybe log it and
3. set the list to the adapter after the loop

That may fix the undesired behaviour of showing only the last of the desired items.